# What is the best way of retrieving a list with all the participants from a Google Meets conference? Is it possible?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, google-api

I am trying to find a way to retrieve all participants from a meets conference. From what it seems, there isn't a direct way of accessing meets through an API, therefore I am considering scraping the data with python but there would be complications with the account validation that happens before joining a conference.

What other options should I consider? Am I excluding something?

Thank you in advance!